# My recyclerview resets when I add or delete an item from a Table (with Room) in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

First of all, I am Spanish so my english is not good.

I have an app with Kotlin and room, and it has a Recyclerview.

I have 3 tables: coaster, user and favorite.

The user can add coasters to favorite, and this is done succesfully.

The problem that I have is that when the user clicks on the button to add or delete from favorites, the recyclerview resets, it displays again. So it scrolls to the top of the Screen, and also some odd spaces appears after the element.

I also have a function to search, and it happens the same: spaces appears after each element when I am searching.

I have tried everything: notifyItemChanged,
notifyDataSetChanged... it doesnt work! I also tried removing the observer once from the recyclerview...
My main activity:

```
class CoasterFragment : Fragment() {
lateinit var coasterListener: CoasterListener
lateinit var usuarioCoaster: List\<UsuarioCoaster\>
private lateinit var searchView: SearchView
private lateinit var cAdapter: CoasterRecyclerViewAdapter
private var \_binding: FragmentCoasterBinding? = null
private val binding get() = \_binding!!

     private val viewModel: CoastersViewModel by viewModels()
     override fun onCreateView(
             inflater: LayoutInflater,
             container: ViewGroup?,
             savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    
         ): View {
         _binding = FragmentCoasterBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
         val root: View = binding.root
    
    
    
        /* val livedata = viewModel.coasters()
         livedata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,object: Observer <List<CoasterFavorito>>  {
             override fun onChanged(it: List<CoasterFavorito>) {
                 createRecyclerView(it)
                 livedata.removeObserver(this)
             }
         })*/
         viewModel.coasters().observe(viewLifecycleOwner){createRecyclerView(it)}
    
    
         coasterListener = CoasterListenerImpl(requireContext(), viewModel)
    
    
    
         searchView = binding.search
         searchView.clearFocus()
         searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
             override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                 if(query != null){
                     searchDatabase(query)
                 }
                 return true
             }
             override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
                 if(query != null){
                     searchDatabase(query)
                 }
                 return true
             }
         })
    
         return root
     }
    
     fun createRecyclerView(coasters: List<CoasterFavorito>) {
    
         cAdapter =
             CoasterRecyclerViewAdapter(
    
                 coasters as MutableList<CoasterFavorito>,
    
                 coasterListener,
                 requireContext()
             )
         val recyclerView = binding.recyclerCoaster
         recyclerView.apply {
    
             layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
             adapter = cAdapter
             addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL))
             cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    
         }
     }
    
    
    
     fun searchDatabase(query: String) {
         val searchQuery = "%$query%"
    
    
         viewModel.searchDatabase(searchQuery).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { createRecyclerView(it)
         }
     }
    
     override fun onDestroyView() {
         super.onDestroyView()
         _binding = null
     }

}
```

my adapter:

```
class  CoasterRecyclerViewAdapter(val coasters: List<CoasterFavorito>, val listener: CoasterListener,
                                  val context: Context,  )  : RecyclerView.Adapter<CoasterRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(){





    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: CoasterItemBinding, private val listener: CoasterListener,
                                         private val context: Context): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){


        fun relleno(data: CoasterFavorito){
            binding.nombre.text = data.coaster.nombre
            binding.parque.text = data.coaster.parque
            binding.ciudad.text = data.coaster.ciudad
            binding.provincia.text = data.coaster.provincia
            binding.comunidad.text = data.coaster.comunidadAutonoma


            Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(data.coaster.imagen)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(binding.imagen)

            binding.check.isChecked = data.favorito

           binding.check.setOnClickListener{
                if (data.favorito) {
                    listener.delFavorito(data.coaster.id)
                    binding.check.isChecked = false

                } else {
                    listener.addFavorito(data.coaster.id)

                    binding.check.isChecked = true

                }
            }
        }
        companion object{
            fun crearViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, listener: CoasterListener, adapter: CoasterRecyclerViewAdapter, context: Context):ViewHolder{
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = CoasterItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding, listener, context )
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ViewHolder.crearViewHolder(parent, listener, this,  context)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.relleno(coasters[position])
    override fun getItemCount() = coasters.size
}

interface CoasterListener {
    fun addFavorito(id: Long)
    fun delFavorito(id: Long)
}
```

I have tried everything: notifyItemChanged,
notifyDataSetChanged... it doesnt work! I also tried removing the observer once from the recyclerview...

Answer (score 0):

Your `createRecyclerView` function should be invoked only once in a whole lifecycle of the `Fragment`. You **should not** create any new `RecyclerView.Adapter`, or set a `LayoutManager` to the `RecyclerView` every time your data set changes.

Therefore the `Observer` used in `viewModel.coasters.observe()` should only submit a new `List` to the existing `Adapter` and call `.notifyDataSetChanged()`, or other notifying functions.

Comment: Could you tell me please how to do that?? Thank you very much